# Xamarin.forms application testing on iOS device

Tags: android, ios, testing, device

I am developing an application in Xamarin.forms cross platform. I can test my application on my anroid device. But I can not test it on an iOS device. How can I test the iPhone phone if I can test it after I connect the android device with cable without putting the app in the app store? I tried the way to build the Ipa, but I did not. If so, can you express it clearly? Because I am very new in mobile application yet. Thanks in advance for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test iOS application: macbook + xcode + ios simulator (for tests with real devices you must have Apple Developer license, is about 99$ per year).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have these features. But I do not know how to get my xamarin.forms application based on windows based project. I have examined the related documents but have not been able to do it on the way home.